# The MOST general solution to the wave equation in 1+1D

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves

(Question at the bottom) The classical wave equation in 1+1D is:
$$\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial x^2}=\frac{1}{v^2}\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial t^2}.$$

It can be solved using the following method. Let's take $a = x+vt$ and $b = x-vt$. Now $a$ and $b$ are both functions of $x$ and $t$, $ a = a(x,t), b = b(x,t)$.

Now $y(x,t)$ can be written in terms of functions of $a$ and $b$.

We can define a new function which is $\widetilde{y}(a,b) = y(x(a,b),t(a,b))$.

Coming back from $\widetilde{y}$ is also possible.
$y(x,t) = \widetilde{y}(a(x,t),b(x,t))$, putting $x$ and $t$ instead of $a$ an $b$.

Now using the above relation let's take a derivative

$$
\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial\widetilde{y}}{\partial a}\frac{\partial a}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial \widetilde{y}}{\partial b}\frac{\partial b}{\partial x}
$$

But we know that
$$
\frac{\partial a}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial b}{\partial x} = 1
$$
Second derivative becomes
$$
\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial x^2} = (\frac{\partial }{\partial a} + \frac{\partial }{\partial b})(\frac{\partial }{\partial a} + \frac{\partial }{\partial b})\widetilde{y} \\
= \frac{\partial^2 \widetilde{y}}{\partial a^2} + \frac{\partial^2 \widetilde{y}}{\partial b^2} + 2\frac{\partial^2 \widetilde{y}}{\partial a \partial b}
$$
By the same token,
$$
\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial t^2} = v^2(\frac{\partial^2 \widetilde{y}}{\partial a^2} + \frac{\partial^2 \widetilde{y}}{\partial b^2} - 2\frac{\partial^2 \widetilde{y}}{\partial a \partial b})
$$

If we put these equations into our wave equation (simply subtract one from the other) we get
$$
\frac{\partial^2 \widetilde{y}}{\partial a \partial b} = 0
$$
This equation tells us that derivative of $\widetilde{y}$ with respect to a does not depend on b, or vice versa. Therefore, we can write $\widetilde{y}$ as
$$
\widetilde{y}(a,b) = f(a) + g(b)
$$
where $f$ and $g$ are some arbitrary functions. Simply put x and t instead of $a$ and $b$ to get $y$.
$$
{y}(x,t) = f(x+vt) + g(x-vt)
$$

So we have just found our general solution. My question is whether or not it is the MOST general solution? I saw somewhere that $$
{y}(x,t) = pf(x+vt) + qg(x-vt)
$$ is the MOST general solution where $p$ and $q$ are two constants. Is it correct? Why/why not? If it's correct, then how can we derive it?

Comment: $pf(a)$ is just as arbitrary a function as $f(a)$

Comment: $pf(x+vt)+qg(x-vt)$ is just a version of $F(x+vt)+G(x-vt)$ with $F(x)=p(f(x)$, $G(x)=qg(x)$.

Comment: So, can we say that if $f(a)+g(b)$ is a solution of an ODE/PDE, then $pf(a)+qg(b)$ will also always be a solution? Or is there any specific condition when this holds?

Comment: If $g$ and $f$ are two generic functions, as in you case, then yes, because $p f$ and $q g$ are two generic functions as well. If you want to understand how to link the generic solution to a specific one (i.e. one that comes from the evolution of a specific initial condition), try to have a look at the d'Alembert formula: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_formula

Comment: This belongs on Math SE IMO.

Comment: @BioPhysicist I think this is a physics question.  But could be either.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the boundary conditions  and the initial conditions. The situation is a bit more complicated here than in the case of the ordinary differential equations, where the most general solution is expressed up to several constants. With partial differential equations the equation alone is insufficient to decide whether the problem is mathematically [well posed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-posed_problem).

Answer (score 1):

The wave equation is second order and requires two initial conditions for a complete solution.

The specific solution with initial conditions is given by D'Alembert's formula (per Quillo):

$$u(x,t)= \frac 1{2c}[ f(x+t)+ f(x-t) ]+ \frac1{2c} \int_{x-ct}^{x+ct} g(y)dy$$

where the initial conditions $f(x,0)$ and $g(x,0)$ are the displacement and speed of displacement at $t=0$. (I re used the variable names $f$ and $g$)

Re. your last question; mike stone answered it in the comments.